# vertical line chart (time series) in jqplot

Tags: javascript, charts, plot, jqplot

I'm trying to plot a time-series in a vertical line chart, something like this:

[EDIT The link is now a demos in the download archive which is available here:

https://www.rgraph.net/download.html#stable

And the demo is called demos/scatter-vertical-line.html ]

The reason is simple: mobile phones have a "vertical" aspect ratio, so a x-based chart is not as effective.

Is there any way I can do it with jqplot? I tried the "rotate" property in css, but it's not available in Opera Mini so I can't use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this should do it :

`seriesDefaults: {rendererOptions: {barDirection: 'horizontal'}}`.

Comment: Weird, I thought `barDirection` only worked for bar charts, but it looks like it's working for line charts as well: http://jsfiddle.net/UfBu6/7/